# Path to created sqlite database different for iPhone and iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-simulator

I have a strange problem here. We recently added iPad functionality to an existing iPhone app. And one day the app didn't start in the iPad simulator. Reason is: The path to the SQLite database is different in the iPad simulator.

The following scenario works: I launch the app in the iPhone 5.0 Simulator, let the database be created. Then I start the same target in the iPad simulator, the check if the database file exists passes and the app launches.

When I delete the app from iPhone simulator and launch it on the iPad sim first, it crashes because the `persistentStoreCoordinator` is not getting created.

The database path is retrieved within `[MyAppAppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]` like so:

```
NSString *databasePath = [[MyApplication sharedApplication] databaseFilePath];
```

And the corresponding methods to that line are:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]; // objectAtIndex:0 didn't make any difference
}

- (NSString *)databaseFilePath {
    NSString *databasePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyApp_v3.sqlite"];
    return databasePath;
}
```

Printing the database path reveals the following for *both* iPad and iPhone:

```
/Users/swramba/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/ABF391C4-FCFF-4274-8FD1-E560C2FB58D9/Documents/MyApp_v3.sqlite
```

**And now the real problem ...**

However, when I let the iPad create the database, the sqlite file is not under this path but rather in the `_Content` subdirectory of the `Documents` folder.

How come the iPad Simulator puts it there and the iPhone Simulator doesn't? And why does he even do so, when the `databaseFilePath` is the exact same in both simulators?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Sebastian

**edit 1:**

This is where the persistentStoreCoordinator *should* be created, but the application never reaches this code on iPad simulator. (Because it first checks if the file exists => NO, then it checks whether the database is being created => NO, set `isCreatingDatabase` to YES (switch to show the alert view). Next time, getter of `persistentStoreCoordinator` gets called, the file still doesn't exist but it has created it, just not where it's supposed to be (`_Content` subdir)

```
if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];
NSLog(@"SB Store URL: %@", storeUrl);

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Comment: Show your database creation code :) (and please ignore my previous answer, now deleted!)

Comment: As you wish ;) Edited my answer